# React Native - Flipper - no application selected (real android device)

Tags: android, react-native, flipper

I am trying to setup flipper with my RN project on real android device (connected with USB). The problem is that flipper is telling me "No application selected", but i can see console.logs and treeview from my app ...

The reason why i want to run flipper is that i want to switch from "React-native-debugger". I also need to enable "Redux debugger" plugin and its not possible, when its telling me "No application selected"
I tried things like "./gradlew clean", clean build folder, or rebuild project with Android studio.

`Desktop flipper: 0.132.0`
package.json:
`"react-native": "~0.66.4",`
`"react-native-flipper": "^0.131.1",`
`"redux-flipper": "^2.0.1",`

gradle.properties:
`FLIPPER_VERSION=0.132.0`

I am including some screenshots:
https://prnt.sc/26sma2d
https://prnt.sc/26smaon

Any ideas why it's not showing application in flipper?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve that, open `ReactNativeFlipper.java` file

In the first line `package com.yourappname;` change it to exactly your package name inside `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Thank you for your idea Tuan. Since i wasnt able to solve this problem (few months ago). I've decided to create new React Native project and move all files to the new project. Since then, the flipper is working correctly :D . But it took me one week to solve this migration...

Maybe someone will find your answer as the right one ;)

Comment: Can you look back at previous project, I believe they're mismatch in the package name

Comment: Upgrading npm package and changing `package com.yourappname.xyz` to `package com.yourappname` in `ReactNativeFlipper.java` woked for me.